# I got ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on subdomain

Tags: wordpress, apache2

I have script to deploy auto my wordpress on apache2 automatically whenever developer commit code to any branch with subdomain is branchname but I’m receiving ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.
My site is https://feature_fabfitfuntheme.shop.fffdev.com/
The strange thing is that when I go to a sub-page such as https://feature_fabfitfuntheme.shop.fffdev.com/welcome/ it works perfectly fine.
This is my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error. Just changed the URL to lower case.
[image]